# Python fernet invalid token

Tags: python, encryption, fernet

Hey guys ive been working on this for days now using bcrypt and other methods to store an encrypted password in a mysql server. Nothing seems to be working, and no one seems to be having a solution to this problem. Currently using fernet as a replacement for bcrypt but it still does not work. I created a class to encrypt:

```
class PwdCipher:
    def generate_key(self,usr:str):
        if os.path.isfile("pass_keys/"+usr+".key"):
            return 1
        else:
            key = Fernet.generate_key()
            with open("pass_keys/"+usr+".key","wb") as key_file:
                key_file.write(key)
            return 0

    def load_key(self,usr:str):
        if os.path.isfile("pass_keys/"+usr+".key"):
            return open("pass_keys/"+usr+".key","rb").read()
        else:
            return 1

    def encrypt(self,usr:str,pwd:str):
        if self.generate_key(usr) == 0:
            key = self.load_key(usr)
            encoded_pwd = pwd.encode()
            f = Fernet(key)
            return f.encrypt(encoded_pwd)
        else:
            return 1

    def decrypt(self,usr:str,encrypted_pwd):
        if self.load_key(usr) == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            key = self.load_key(usr)
            f = Fernet(key)
            encoded_pwd = encrypted_pwd.encode()
            decrypted_msg = f.decrypt(encoded_pwd)
            print(decrypted_msg)
```

Which is called on by this:

```
    def root_task_handler(self,task):
        if task[0][2:] ==  "create_user":
            usr = task[1]
            pwd = task[2]
            email = task[3][:-1]
            encrypted_pwd = self.pwd_cipher.encrypt(usr,pwd)
            if encrypted_pwd == 1:
                print("[" + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - INFO] " + "USR KEY ALREADY EXISTS ...ABORTING " + usr)
            else:
                if self.query.create_user(usr,encrypted_pwd,email) == 0:
                    print("[" + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " - INFO] " + "ROOT USER CREATED ACCOUNT " + usr)
        elif task[0][2:] ==  "delete_user":
            usr = task[1]
            pwd = task[2][:-1]
            encrypted_pwd = self.query.get_password(usr)
            db_pwd = self.pwd_cipher.decrypt(usr,encrypted_pwd)
```

Im begging for an answer at this point. Please if you know anything let me know! I would appreciate this a lot:)

Comment: Please edit the _full_ error message into your question. You should remove the tag `sockets` as your question doesn’t appear in any way related to that.

Comment: Also please edit the code in your question to be a [mre] complete with imports and sample data needed, so I can paste the code into a file and run it _without adding anything_

Comment: thanks ill try that!

Answer (score 1):

```
class PwdCipher:
def generate_key(self,usr:str):
    if os.path.isfile("pass_keys/"+usr+".key"):
        return 1
    else:
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        with open("pass_keys/"+usr+".key","wb") as key_file:
            key_file.write(key)
        return 0

def load_key(self,usr:str):
    if os.path.isfile("pass_keys/"+usr+".key"):
        return open("pass_keys/"+usr+".key","rb").read()
    else:
        return 1

def encrypt(self,usr:str,pwd:str):
    key_result = self.generate_key(usr)
    if key_result == 0:
        key = self.load_key(usr)
        encoded_pwd = pwd.encode()
        f = Fernet(key)
        encrypted_pwd = f.encrypt(encoded_pwd)
        return encrypted_pwd
    else:
        return None

def decrypt(self,usr:str,encrypted_pwd):
    key_result = self.load_key(usr)
    if key_result == 0:
        key = self.load_key(usr)
        f = Fernet(key)
        try:
            decrypted_msg = f.decrypt(encrypted_pwd)
            return decrypted_msg.decode() #Return as a string
        except InvaildToken:
            return None  #Return Non for decryption failure
    else:
        return None
```

The changes I made in the encrypt and decrypt functions.
I make sure that the encrypt is returning the encrypted password as bytes
The encrypt func return the encrypted password and the decrypt func return the decrypted password as string or None in case of decryption failure

This

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to my question. But a solution is to just encrypt the password in MySql. The only thing that works.